# How to only update a row in Telerik MVC grid without refreshing the grid data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

From the samples and documentation, it looks like if I want to update one row (or do a batch update) in a Telerik grid, I also need to refresh the data in the entire grid.

Is there a way to just update that one row on the client and not return all the grid data every time I want to do an update?  It seems extremely wasteful to keep returning that much data every time.
Even if I do a batch update, why do I need to return all the new data?

Answer (score 0):

Generally a database has many users, and your user interface may be accessed by multiple people. If the grid is going to update, then it will include any other changes that may have happened to the data since the grid originally loaded.

The grid allows you to limit the number of records that are shown at a time via the paging option. On our project we are loading the grid with AJAX, and using `IQueryable`'s in the controller. When we call `ToDataSourceResult(request)` on the IQueryable, it only retrieves the data that is needed, and does not load the full table from the database.

On the Razor View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<WebApp.ViewModels.AccountViewModel>()
    .Name("Accounts")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.AccountNumber);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Address1);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Address2);
        columns.Bound(c => c.City);
        columns.Bound(c => c.State);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Zip);
        columns.Bound(c => c.PrimaryContact).Title("Contact");
    })
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
        .Extra(false)
        .Operators(operators => operators
            .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                .Contains("Contains")
                .DoesNotContain("Doesn't Contain")
            )
        )
    )
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(new int[] { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 500 })
        .ButtonCount(5)
    )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("Name").Ascending())
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Account_Read", "Account"))
    )
)
```

Then in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Account_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var jsonlist = GetAccounts()
        .Select(sa => new AccountViewModel
        {
            ID = sa.ID,
            AccountNumber = sa.AccountNumber,
            Name = sa.Name,
            Address1 = sa.Address1,
            Address2 = sa.Address2,
            City = sa.City,
            State = sa.State,
            Zip = sa.Zip,
            PrimaryContact = sa.User.FirstName + " " + sa.User.LastName
        }
    ).ToDataSourceResult(request);

    return Json(jsonlist);
}
```

**UPDATE**

We have an inline edit form on one of our Kendo grids. It took us a bit to get it how we watned. In the Razor View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DataViewModel>()
    .Name("Data")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.FieldName)
            .EditorTemplateName("DataFieldName")
            .Title("Item Name")
            .Width(200);
        columns.Bound(c => c.TextValue)
            .Title("Text");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); })
            .Title("Actions")
            .Width(172);
    })
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(new int[] { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 })
        .ButtonCount(5)
    )
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("CreatedDate").Descending())
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(pd => pd.ID);
                    model.Field(pd => pd.CreatedDate).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(pd => pd.ValuesID).DefaultValue(Model.Values.ID);
                })
        .Read(read => read.Action("Data_Read", "History", new { ValuesID = Model.Values.ID }))
        .Create(update => update.Action("Data_Create", "History"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Data_Update", "History"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("Data_Destroy", "History"))
    )
)

<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

In order to use the Kendo date time picker for the date option, we had to create a custom editor template. We created a new folder under `Views >> Shared >> EditorTemplates`. The file name is DataFieldName.cshtml:

```
@model WebApp.ViewModels.DataViewModel
@using WebApp.ViewModels

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Name("FieldName")
    .Placeholder("Select/Create Item Name")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("Name")
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .DataSource(source => source
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetFieldNames", "History"))
    )
)
```

Then the controller has all of the action results for the AJAX calls:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Data_Create(DataViewModel DataIn)
{
    var Data = new Data();
    Data.ValuesID = DataIn.ValuesID;
    Data.FieldName = DataIn.FieldName;
    Data.TextValue = DataIn.TextValue;
    if (DataIn.TimeValue != null) Data.TimeValue = DataIn.TimeValue;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Datas.Add(Data);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("EditValue", new
    {
        ValueID = DataIn.ValuesID,
        tankID = db.Values.FirstOrDefault(pv => pv.ID == DataIn.ValuesID).TankID
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Data_Update(DataViewModel DataIn)
{
    var Data = db.Datas.Find(DataIn.ID);
    Data.FieldName = DataIn.FieldName;
    Data.TextValue = DataIn.TextValue;
    if (DataIn.TimeValue != null) Data.TimeValue = DataIn.TimeValue;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(Data).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("EditValue", new
    {
        ValueID = DataIn.ValuesID,
        tkID = db.Values.FirstOrDefault(pv => pv.ID == DataIn.ValuesID).tkID
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Data_Destroy(DataViewModel DataIn)
{
    var Data = db.Datas.Find(DataIn.ID);

    db.Datas.Remove(Data);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("EditValue", new
    {
        ValueID = DataIn.ValuesID,
        tkID = db.Values.FirstOrDefault(pv => pv.ID == DataIn.ValuesID).tkID
    });
}

public ActionResult GetFieldNames()
{
    var jsonList = db.Datas
        .Select(pd => new 
        {
            Name = pd.FieldName 
        })
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(pd => pd.Name)
        .ToList();

    return Json(jsonList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: This is a great point.  The underlying reason why we want to do this is because we have a query form for the grid data, and on update row, the query data is not getting passed back.  So we are unable to get the grid data.  Is there a way to attach more data to the update call?

Comment: Ok, I will post an example of our grid where we used the grid commands to update the records... maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

*Single Row Update*

If you want to update a single row without refreshing the whole grid, for instance, if you are going to update a row's Age column you can do the following:

```
var name ="Alex Mahon"; // we use a variable called 'name' to get the row we're gonna update

var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"); // change 'grid' with your grid's id

var row = $('#grid tr:has(td:contains(' + name + '))'); // change 'name' with your variable, it is basically a column value in your grid to catch the row to be updated

var data = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(row); // we get the data item

data.set("Age", args.response.authId); // change 'Age' with your grid column name you're gonna update
```

That's it! Now you should see the changes reflected to your grid.